# why is the method of assigning one to another is different from assigning two individual variables in C++?

Tags: c++, arrays, memory-address

so in the picture, it says that the problem is with the starting address of the array as we cant change it. but why does this apply only for arrays.  `int x = 1;` we could easily say `int y = x;` and it would work. doesnt this change the memory address of the variable too?

[image]

Comment: It applies for all variables including an integer. When you write x=y; You are not changing the address of variable x or y you are copying the value of y and putting it in x.

Comment: The words in the picture present an over-simplification of the situation, and you might be exploring one of the shortcomings of this simplification. (A more accurate description of the situation would get into lvalues et al.) However, since no one is going to be able to find this question by searching for the words in the picture, I do not see this question having long-term use.

Comment: @JaMiT I copied what I consider to be the most egregious parts in my answer ;-) That said, I don't understand all the downvotes. The quoted text is seriously dubious, but that's not OP's fault. If anything, it explains the confusion behind the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[*tl;dr*] The first and sole reason why `newValues = oldValues;` is illegal ("*will not work*") is that the C++ standard prohibits it. Array assignment is not defined, supported or allowed in C++, and therefore any such statement is invalid code. Any other attempts to "explain" it, using memory addresses or other speculations, only obfuscates the simple truth that it is the definition of the language that decides what is legal and what is not in that language.

The following are quoted from the posted "textbook" excerpt, which I find to be both wrong and misguided for what looks to be an introduction to C++ basics.

> *the name of an array without the brackets and subscript stands for the array's starting memory address*

Wrong. The name stands for the variable that it denotes, which has `array` type. While it is true that an array can decay to a pointer ("*starting memory address*) in certain contexts, it is certainly not true that an array name *is* the same with its starting address. For example, both `sizeof oldValues` and `typeid(oldValues)` are valid expressions, which would mean something very different if replacing `oldValues` with its memory address.

> *the statement will not work because you cannot change the starting memory address of an array*

The statement "*will not work*" is correct, but the given reason is still wrong. No assignment changes the *address* of its left-hand side, it only changes its value. Array assignment does not work because the language does not define it, and for no other reason. Consider for example the following.

```
int a[4], b[4];
a = b;  // error, array assignment not allowed

struct { int n[4]; } c, d;
c = d;  // ok, using default copy assignment
```